# Service Fabric Stateless Services Asp.Net Core- Oauth2.0 Bearer Token Error

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, service-fabric-stateless

I am using Service Fabric Stateless Service Asp.net & trying to implement Oauth 2.0 , but i am getting error under Startup.cs & ServiceInstanceListener

Could not resolve a service of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' for the parameter 'appBuilder' of method 'Configure' on type 'AuthenticationService.Startup

I dont find ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) under StartUp.cs of Service.

Code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAppBuilder appBuilder) {

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    **var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ConfigureOAuth(appBuilder);
    appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);**

}
public void **ConfigureOAuth**(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

}
```

Edit Fixed Code Block...

Answer (score 0):

I think you using references from .Net Framework with Owin rather that use .NET Core.
Try remove ConfigureOauth method
and use this code snippet in your ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs file

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
  {
    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    cfg.SaveToken = true;

    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
      ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
      ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
    };

  });
```

Comment: I have to use Owin Oauth 2.0 with Service Fabric Stateless Service WEB API (Asp.Net COre2.0) .    I m using Asp.Net Core Stateless Service. My Concern is how to call ConfigureOuath in startup constructor or ConfigureServices